# Why do i get unexpected character "EOF"?

Tags: angular

Can someone please help me with this. I am breaking my head to resolve this

[image]

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite Food</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedFood">
    <mat-option></mat-option>
    @for (option of foods; track option) {
      <mat-option [value]="option.value">{{ option.viewValue }}</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @SamK What version of angular are you using, new syntax works on angular 17 I guess?

Comment: oh ok.. i am using 16 i guess.. let me upgrade to 17 and try.. thank you Naren

Comment: I upgraded to Angular 17, however, i still see this error, i don't get compile error though. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Update your linter